# Error executing script Clean: org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Tags: grails

Java version 1.6
Grails version 2.0.0

When I execute grails clean I get

```
Error executing script Clean: org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

C:\projects\botServices>grails --stacktrace clean
| Configuring classpath
| Error Error executing script Clean: org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.class$(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.$get$$class$org$codehaus$gant$GantBuilder(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.<init>(GantBinding.groovy:41)
| Error Error executing script Clean: org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder
```

I never faced this issue previously. Strange.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue in my Mac(Leopard). It was due the fact that JAVA_HOME is not pointing to jdk 1.6
It could be addressed in couple of ways

1. export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home
   ( if only for that particular session)
2. update ~/.profile if you need  Java_Home to be reflected every time

Hope that helps